# Change port of domain GlassFish using asadmin

Tags: glassfish, port

Is there any way or `command` to change the **port** 4848 to 4949 of Glassfish?

**N.B**

I don't want to change it from **domain.xml**

Comment: Which port? GlassFish is configured to bind to a lot of ports for a lot of reasons. Any change to the configuration can be handled by the `asadmin set` command, then using the correct dotted name for the setting

Comment: On Linux, you can use the `asadmin get` command with a wildcard and grep to get a list of all the settings containing "`.port=`" as follows:     `asadmin get "*" | grep -v "default-config" | grep "\.port="`

Comment: Thank you Mike, i want to change the port 4848 to 4949 par example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

> asadmin set
>   configs.config.server-config.network-config.network-listeners.network-listener.admin-listener.port=4949

or

> asadmin set
>   server.http-service.http-listener.admin-listener.port=4949

to change the port of the "admin" HTTP listener which is configured in Glassfish. To change the port of the "main" port, change "admin-listener" in the command to "http-listener-1".

Comment: Thank you @unwichtich, this should help me

Comment: This is correct, but the listener which binds to 4848 is the admin listener. You can use this dotted name: `configs.config.server-config.network-config.network-listeners.network-listener.admin-listener.port=4848`

Comment: @unwichtich i want to change the port 4848 not the other ports!!

Comment: the port 4848 still not change, but the port 8080 changed to 4949

Comment: Looks like you changed the port of http-listener-1 to 4949, now you can't change admin-listener to this port because it is in use...you have to change back http-listener-1 (previously port 8080) to 8080, then change admin-listener to 4949.

Comment: any way to do something equivalent/make this change _before_ starting the domain?

Comment: You can just edit your `domain.xml`. Make sure to change the port in the `server-config`. If you want to script it you can use something like `sed` or package a preconfigured `domain.xml` and copy that to the desired location.